# How to SetDefault()?

Tags: wxpython

I'm new to wxpython but I have to edit a (large) given code:

```
bsButtons = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
self.cmdOk = wx.Button(self, label=_(u"Ok"))
self.cmdOk.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOk)
bsButtons.Add(self.cmdOk,
              border=4,
              flag=wx.RIGHT)
self.cmdCancel = wx.Button(self, label=_(u"Abbrechen"))
self.cmdCancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel)
bsButtons.Add(self.cmdCancel)
```

...

```
def OnOk(self, event):
    self.EndModal(wx.ID_OK)
def OnCancel(self, event):
    self.EndModal(wx.ID_CANCEL)
```

I want to set the focus on the "OK" Button by default, so that the "Enter"-Key will execute this button. I already tried to add this line:

```
self.cmdOk.SetDefault()
```

But this didn't work. (no error, but pressing Enter didn't had an effect)
Anyone who can help me? Thanks!

Edit:
I inserted the following:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.on_key_down)

...

    def on_key_down(self, event):
        if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_RETURN:
            self.EndModal(wx.ID_OK)
        else:
            event.Skip()
```

But this does not work. There is missing something: I know the first line has to look like this:

```
self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
```

But I don't know what "button" is in my case?!

Edit2:
Finally it works:

```
self.etcFormula.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.on_key_down)
```

etcFormula is the edit line I was talking about (where the focus is). So now I understood that I have to refer to this edit line when I want to catch the Enter-button.

Comment: `button` will just be an instance of the `wx.Button` class so in your case `self.cmdOk` and `self.cmdCancel` are equivalent, but you've already defined handlers for these so I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do now?

Comment: I think I didn't explained it right: The focus is on an edit line but when I press "Enter"-Key, the "OnOk"-Command shall be executed. Compare my 2nd edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `self.cmdOk.SetFocus()` should do it.

Edit:

If you want to handle the enter via a text field you could add a handler along these lines bound to `wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN`.

```
def on_key_down(event):
    if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.K_RETURN:
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_OK)
    else:
         event.Skip()
```

Comment: Ups, sorry, that's not what i wanted. Sorry, i explained it wrong: The focus shouldn't be on my OK button - the focus shall be at a edit line (it was already there before). But when i press Enter (even with focus on edit line) the "OK" button shall be executed.

Comment: Ah, well the focus can only be in one place at a time so in your case that will have to be the text field.  I've added an edit to my answer which should do this.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried but got a few error messages, so i googlet and changed your code a little -> pls have a look at my edit. What's the difference between K_Return and WXK_RETURN?

Comment: They're just aliases of the same value so either should work. I've never quite understood the reason behind it but I suspect it's something to with the wxWidgets convention of prefixing everything with wx being 'un-Pythonic'.